# Conditional compilation of documents using command line options for pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, options

Is it possible to compile two different pdf outputs from the same `.tex` file?

For example, let's say I have a document `main.tex`
which contains questions for students,
and answers only for teachers, which I want to hide from the students.
Is it possible to compile the student and teacher versions of the document
from the command line with different options?

```
pdflatex '\documentversion{student}' main -o student.pdf # output is student.pdf
pdflatex '\documentversion{teacher}' main -o teacher.pdf # output is teacher.pdf
```

Comment: The linked question (and its answer) partially answers this question. I vote to reopen this question and provide a complete answer...

Comment: @PaulGaborit It's reopened now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an example.

You must compile this document with this two commands to get the two versions (`students.pdf` and `teachers.pdf`):

```
pdflatex -jobname=students '\def\student{}\input{main}'
pdflatex -jobname=teachers '\def\teachers{}\input{main}'
```

(The `-jobname` option defines the name of the produced PDF document. Ex: with `-jobname=students` option, the command produces `students.pdf`.)

The `main.tex` document (using `etoolbox` to simplify the test):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
  \ifdef{\teachers}
  {Content for teachers}
  {Content for students}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain the use of `jobname`?

Comment: @Praxeolitic Done...

Comment: Looks like that was a silly question. I was confused and had thought it was part of getting the conditional to work.

Comment: How would multiple variables be accomplished?

Comment: @notlesh I do not understand your question: why do you want multiple "variables"? to produce multiple documents?